# Portal - Look Up and Look Down commands are not working

Tags: pc, portal

I am attempting to control the camera with the arrow keys in Portal 1. I bound the arrow keys to the 'Turn Left and Right' and 'Look up and down' commands in Settings, but when I tried to play, I could only turn left and right, looking up and down didn't work. I tried rebinding the keys, using the developer's console, and restarting Portal, but nothing worked. Portal works fine, and I can move with my mouse.

Is there some special command or binding I have to use, or do the Look Up and Look Down commands not work at all?

Comment: What controller are you using?

Comment: @Ktash I'm not sure, but Portal interprets each key as a keyboard key. For instance, a D-Pad interprets as the arrow keys. But I even tried using the keyboard to do it, and it doesn't work.

Comment: If you disconnect the game pad, are you able to look around with the mouse/keyboard?

Comment: @Ktash Mouse - yes (even when it's plugged in). Keyboard - no.

Comment: It's a known problem with Source Engine which Portal 2 is built on, you can only look up and down with an official XBox 360 controller, or a mouse.

Comment: @Rokk (Note: This is  Portal 1.) Then why are those commands there in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Commands Look Up and Look down do work. The command you're looking for is "cl_mouselook"
- Set to 1 to use mouse for look, 0 for keyboard look. Cannot be set while connected to a server.

Needs to be set to 0 to work with your binding.

You must be on the main menu to be able to set cl_mouselook.

Comment: This is evidently a usage of the word "work" that I was previously unaware of.